# Setting start position in Soundcloud widget

Tags: widget, soundcloud

I am using the Soundcloud widget with the following code:

```
iframe width="100%" height="120" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F90458315&amp;color=429dd1&amp;buying="false";api_seekTo(30);auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true"
```

Is it possible to set the start postition of the song to a specific point, so when the user plays the song it will start at i.e 1m 30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is possible. Heres an example code of how can you do it.

```
var iframeElement   = document.querySelector('iframe');
var widget= SC.Widget(iframeElement);
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY,function(){ //When player is ready, attach an event
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY,function(){ //When song starts playing
        widget.seekTo(90000);//90 seconds from the start = 1:30 min
        widget.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY); //Remove event, to avoid problems when playing is paused and then restarted
    });
});
```

Comment: After adding the SoundCloud Widget JS (https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js) this worked for me out of the box. Surprised this isn't exposed as a parameter on embeds as it is for the other.